# Error compiling Flutter Flame Game on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, flame

Hi I tried to implement Flame Game using the flutter Flame package, however, after compiling properly once, now it does not compile at all, and is showing the error, listed below:

I am running MacOS Moneterey
Androud Studio: Arctic Fox 2020.3.1
Flutter env.
environment:
sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"
flame: ^1.0.0

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/flame_game.dart:19:40: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
class FlameGame extends Component with Game {
                                       ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/game_widget.dart:21:40: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
typedef OverlayWidgetBuilder<T extends Game> = Widget Function(
                                       ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/game_widget.dart:28:28: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
class GameWidget<T extends Game> extends StatefulWidget {
                           ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/game_widget.dart:136:34: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
class _GameWidgetState<T extends Game> extends State<GameWidget<T>> {
                                 ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/game_widget.dart:373:9: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  final Game game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/mixins/fps_counter.dart:9:21: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin FPSCounter on Game {
                    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/mixins/keyboard.dart:48:25: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin KeyboardEvents on Game {
                        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:4:32: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin MultiTouchTapDetector on Game {
                               ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:12:33: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin MultiTouchDragDetector on Game {
                                ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:20:22: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin TapDetector on Game {
                     ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:27:31: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin SecondaryTapDetector on Game {
                              ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:33:28: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin DoubleTapDetector on Game {
                           ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:39:28: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin LongPressDetector on Game {
                           ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:47:31: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin VerticalDragDetector on Game {
                              ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:55:33: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin HorizontalDragDetector on Game {
                                ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:63:29: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin ForcePressDetector on Game {
                            ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:70:22: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin PanDetector on Game {
                     ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:78:24: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin ScaleDetector on Game {
                       ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:84:32: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin MouseMovementDetector on Game {
                               ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart:88:25: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
mixin ScrollDetector on Game {
                        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:18:9: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:46:9: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:74:9: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:88:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:95:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:102:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:112:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:119:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:128:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:137:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:144:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:151:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:158:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:167:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:173:9: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:188:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:194:9: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:217:5: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/parallax.dart:16:32: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
extension ParallaxExtension on Game {
                               ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/sprite_batch.dart:10:35: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
extension SpriteBatchExtension on Game {
                                  ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_render_box.dart:15:3: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  Game game;
  ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:12:31: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
bool hasBasicGestureDetectors(Game game) =>
                              ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:23:35: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
bool hasAdvancedGesturesDetectors(Game game) =>
                                  ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:29:24: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
bool hasMouseDetectors(Game game) =>
                       ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:34:36: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
Widget applyBasicGesturesDetectors(Game game, Widget child) {
                                   ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:182:39: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
Widget applyAdvancedGesturesDetectors(Game game, Widget child) {
                                      ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:277:28: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
Widget applyMouseDetectors(Game game, Widget child) {
                           ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:294:9: Error: Type 'Game' not found.
  final Game gameRef;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/flame_game.dart:19:7: Error: The type 'Game' can't be mixed in.
class FlameGame extends Component with Game {
      ^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/components/component.dart:334:20: Error: The getter 'hasLayout' isn't defined for the class 'FlameGame'.
 - 'FlameGame' is from 'package:flame/src/game/flame_game.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/flame_game.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'hasLayout'.
        parentGame.hasLayout,
                   ^^^^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/game_widget.dart:373:9: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  final Game game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:18:9: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:46:9: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:74:9: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:88:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:95:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:102:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:112:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:119:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:128:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:137:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:144:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:151:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:158:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:167:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:173:9: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:188:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:194:9: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  final Game _game;
        ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/gestures/events.dart:217:5: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
    Game game,
    ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_render_box.dart:15:3: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  Game game;
  ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:12:31: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
bool hasBasicGestureDetectors(Game game) =>
                              ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:23:35: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
bool hasAdvancedGesturesDetectors(Game game) =>
                                  ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:29:24: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
bool hasMouseDetectors(Game game) =>
                       ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:34:36: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
Widget applyBasicGesturesDetectors(Game game, Widget child) {
                                   ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:182:39: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
Widget applyAdvancedGesturesDetectors(Game game, Widget child) {
                                      ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:203:26: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  void addDragRecognizer(Game game, Drag Function(int, DragStartInfo) config) {
                         ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:277:28: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
Widget applyMouseDetectors(Game game, Widget child) {
                           ^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flame-1.0.0/lib/src/game/game_widget/gestures.dart:294:9: Error: 'Game' isn't a type.
  final Game gameRef;
        ^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

**This is the code that I wrote (copied from the Flame website):**

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/extensions.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flame/palette.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: MyGame(),
    ),
  );
}

class Square extends PositionComponent {
  static const speed = 0.25;
  static const squareSize = 128.0;

  static Paint white = BasicPalette.white.paint();
  static Paint red = BasicPalette.red.paint();
  static Paint blue = BasicPalette.blue.paint();

  @override
  void render(Canvas c) {
    c.drawRect(size.toRect(), white);
    c.drawRect(const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 3, 3), red);
    c.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(width / 2, height / 2, 3, 3), blue);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    angle += speed * dt;
    angle %= 2 * math.pi;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    size.setValues(squareSize, squareSize);
    anchor = Anchor.center;
  }
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame with DoubleTapDetector, TapDetector {
  bool running = true;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    add(
      Square()
        ..x = 100
        ..y = 100,
    );
  }

  @override
  void onTapUp(TapUpInfo info) {
    final touchPoint = info.eventPosition.game;

    final handled = children.any((c) {
      if (c is PositionComponent && c.containsPoint(touchPoint)) {
        remove(c);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    if (!handled) {
      add(Square()..position = touchPoint);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onDoubleTap() {
    if (running) {
      //    pauseEngine();
    } else {
      //    resumeEngine();
    }

    running = !running;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like something is wrong with the Flame version in your cache.
Run:

```sh
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get
```

In the directory of your application, and then try to run the example again.

Comment: one whole day... the whole day I tried to figure this out. Thank you sir!

Comment: No problem, please mark this as the answer if it worked. (checkmark under the score)